# Difference between isna() and isnull() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been using pandas for quite some time. But, I don't understand what's the difference between `isna()` and `isnull()`. And, more importantly, which one to use when identifying missing values in a dataframe.

What is the basic underlying difference of how a value is detected as either `na` or `null`?

Comment: The two functions are same. Both give the missing values.

Comment: Both perform the same task of detecting null values.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

#### Pandas `isna()` vs `isnull()`.

I'm assuming you are referring to [`pandas.DataFrame.isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) vs [`pandas.DataFrame.isnull()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html#pandas.DataFrame.isnull). Not to confuse with [`pandas.isnull()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html), which in contrast to the two above isn't a method of the DataFrame class.

These two DataFrame methods do **exactly** the same thing! Even their docs are identical. You can even confirm this in pandas' [code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/537b65cb0fd2aa318e089c5e38f09e81d1a3fe35/pandas/core/dtypes/missing.py#L109).

#### But why have two methods with different names do the same thing?

This is because pandas' DataFrames are based on R's DataFrames. In R `na` and `null` are two separate things. Read [this post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-na-vs-null/) for more information.

However, in python, pandas is built on top of numpy, which has **neither `na` nor `null`** values. Instead numpy has **`NaN`** values (which stands for "Not a Number"). Consequently, pandas also uses `NaN` values.

#### In short

- To detect `NaN` values numpy uses [`np.isnan()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html).
- To detect `NaN` values pandas uses either `.isna()` or `.isnull()`.
  The `NaN` values are inherited from the fact that pandas is built on top of numpy, while the two functions' names originate from R's DataFrames, whose structure and functionality pandas tried to mimic.

Comment: This explains everything and yes i wanted to infer  'pandas.DataFrame.isna()' vs 'pandas.DataFrame.isnull()' . Thanks for such a detailed explanation.

Comment: Do note that in Pandas 1.0.0 a [new experimental](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#experimental-na-scalar-to-denote-missing-values) `pd.NA` value has been introduced and it might behave differently in certain operations from `np.nan`.

Comment: Can you also confirm that df[df['x'].notnull()] is the same as df[~df['x'].isna()] & df[~df['x'].isnull()]? Only recently seen notnull and want to be sure its safe